# prime numbers algo

Tags: algorithm

I got asked this interview question. After the interview I have googled for a good two hours, and I've not found an answer to what I guess is a common interview question. I want to improve myself and would love to know how to solve this question and questions similar to this. Given integer X, return true if P * P + Q * Q = X

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since this is a programming site I doubt you get an answer without posting some code that shows your efforts so far.

Comment: Googling is good, but thinking about it and trying to solve it yourself is even better. Please share some sort of effort to that effect to make this on topic. There is missing information. What are `p` and `q`? If they're any arbitrary numbers, can `p == q`? Can one or the other or both be 0? What are the constraints for `x`, if any? Examples of input and output with explanation are nice. See [ask].

Comment: Why not simply iterating on `P < sqrt(X/2)`  and check if `Q` exists?

Comment: Hi guys! First of all, thanks for your feedback. @Ripi2: posting a questions without having at least tried to solve it is really, really bad. Posting some code is usually a good way to at least show that you have tried to find an answer before polluting the web. A part from a couple hours of googling, I have only tried to do c.sqrt(). Don't even know exactly way. This questions sounds very algebra-related, and I have no competence in that field. I am sorry that it looks like I haven't even tried to solve this.

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, thanks for the feedback! I had no more info about P and Q, a part from the fact that they are two integers that, when multiplied by themselves and then added, are equal to C. Again, I am very sorry that this question looks like "one of those", and I was very reluctant to post this at first.

Comment: Hi @Damien. It makes me happy that sqrt has something do to with solving this question. As I wrote in response to Ripi2, it was my first intuition to do something with the square of X.  Nevertheless, I am not sure I have understood your solution. My lack of a math background really proves to be problematic with questions like this.

Comment: You don't need much algebra to solve this question. Put yourself (by hand) some values for X and try to find two integers P,Q that obey the condition. Which is your common procedure for all X you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is run a loop from 0 to square root of your input number X, for each loop check that sqrt(X - i^2) is integer or not. If there is an integer return true else return false.

```
#include <math.h>      
#include<iostream>   
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < sqrt(n); i++) {

        if(floor(sqrt(n - i*i))==ceil(sqrt(n - i*i))){
            cout << "true " << i << "^2 + " << sqrt(n - i*i) << "^2 = " << n << endl;    
            return 0;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    cout << " Cant find two integers satifield a^2 + b^2 = n^2\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This algorithm is simple, but with the bigger input it seems to take time to run.

Comment: You can slightly reduce the search by considering P <= Q

Comment: @Damien Yes, I can change the condition like: 
if(floor(sqrt(n - i*i))==ceil(sqrt(n - i*i)) && i <= sqrt(n - i*i)) to reduce the loop. Thank for your suggestion.

Comment: @AlfredoDeNardi let insert : else if (i > sqrt(n - i*i)) break; instead of else continue; for better loop.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have code, so I would give you what the interviewer expects from you:

- only in the comment you identified that P and Q are any integers, that should be part of the question and if not, you should confirm with the interviewer
- you should notice that P and Q are unsigned integer because of the square, also P and Q should no bigger than sqrt(X)
- you should be able to find an answer by brute force search for P, Q from 0 t sqrt(X), and check all combinations
- you can also build a dynamic programming problem from it, namely, list all numbers from 0 to floor(sqrt(X)), then put their square into an array. Afterwards, make an algorithm to search for sum of two elements from the array equals to X

Comment: This is great feedback, thanks adrtam. I'm looking forward to building a dp problem from it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a theorem, called the Sum of Two Squares Theorem, which says:

> An integer greater than one can be written as a sum of two squares if and only if its prime decomposition contains no prime congruent to 3 modulo 4 raised to an odd power.

Perhaps you were expected to know about that.

That check is practical to implement. It requires factoring X, which is known as a difficult problem, but it's only properly difficult for large numbers. If X is a 64bit number, you can easily factor it with Pollard's Rho algorithm, which is not very complicated.

Comment: Very interesting to know the algebraic background of this question. Thanks for your contribution harold. As Ripi2 told me, algebraic was not 100% necessary to solve this question, but it surely helps to know a bit about squares, prime numbers and all the fun stuff. Thanks again.